# Why The Plot Doesnt Show The Real Data

Tags: python, pyvista

I run some code to plot the hypocenters of the earthquake with 3D using pyvista package on python , i got the reference on [gemgis.readthedocs.io](https://gemgis.readthedocs.io/en/stable/getting_started/tutorial/24_plotting_hypocenters_of_earthquakes.html) . I succesed run the code but the plot doesnt show how it was like the reference .. here's mine[image: plot with my own data] , and and this is should be [image: real plot].

I made the modification with the data by arranged the longitude , latitude , depth , and magnitude

and here's my code

```
import geopandas as gpd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pyvista as pv
import numpy as np
import gemgis as gg
df = gpd.read_file("data gempa 2010-2021 talaud.csv")
gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(df, geometry=gpd.points_from_xy(df.X, df.Y))
gdf = gg.vector.extract_xy(gdf=gdf)
test = pv.Sphere(radius=1000, center=gdf.loc[0][['X', "Y", "Z"]].tolist())


spheres = pv.MultiBlock([pv.Sphere(radius=float(gdf.loc[i]["Magnitude"])*200, center=gdf.loc[i][['X', 'Y', 'Z']].tolist()) for i in range(len(gdf))])
for i in range(len(spheres.keys())):
    spheres[spheres.keys()[i]]['Magnitude'] = np.zeros(len(spheres[spheres.keys()[i]].points)) + float(gdf.loc[i]['Magnitude'])


sargs = dict(fmt="%.1f", color='black')


p = pv.Plotter()
p.add_mesh(spheres,scalars='Magnitude', cmap='Reds', clim=[0,6], scalar_bar_args=sargs)
p.set_background('white')
p.show_grid(color='black')
p.enable_stereo_render()
p.show()
```

Comment: The short answer is that your code has mistakes in it. Please [edit] your question and add your code. We can't debug code we can't see. The most likely reason is that your radii for plotting the spheres are too large, so one large sphere hides all the others. Decreasing their size would help with this.

Comment: i'll allready edit my code , but once changed the radius it'll be change the shape of the plot like tube

Comment: Sorry, I don't quite understand your comment about "change the shape of the plot like tube". Do you mean that decreasing the spheres' radius gives different but still wrong results? If that's the case, can you also add the new image to your question?